# How to know when a HTMLMediaElement has finished

Tags: javascript

In javascript I'm playing a sound like this:

```
var mySound = new Audio('/my-url');
mySound.play();
```

Is there a way to know when it has finished to play ? I've seen a `ended` property but I'm more looking for an event, a Promise, or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: [ended, the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended)

Comment: you can answer with this, that's what I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 1):

By using `HTMLMediaElement` like below you can use fined whether media is finished playing or not

```
var obj = document.createElement('video');
console.log(obj.ended);
```

Here `HTMLMediaElement.ended` returns Boolean value stating whether media is finished(TRUE) or not(FALSE).

But, you want another way of handling such event. Thus you can use `jquery` event like below:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').on('ended',function(){
      console.log('Video has ended!');
    });
  });
</script>
```

And without jquery:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',function(){
    console.log('Video has ended!');
  }, false);
</script>
```